# Evaluate a variable when inserting text into a buffer

Tags: insert, template

When I open a fresh file for coding, I like to insert a header like this:

```
#####################################################################   
# Purpose:
# Author: me (me@someplace.com)
# Date:
#####################################################################
```

I keep this text in a file called `header` in `~/.emacs.d/` and I insert it like so:

```
;; Insert header to file 
(defun header()
  "Insert header into file"
  (interactive)
  (insert-file "~/.emacs.d/header"))
```

which I call with `M+x header`. Very cool! I also have a function for adding the date:

```
;; Insert today's date
(defun today ()
  "Insert today's date"
  (interactive)
  (insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

which I invoke with `M+x today` after inserting my header text in order to populate the `Date:` field.

**Q:** Is there a way that I can merge these functions such that the date is *automatically* inserted after `Date:` when I insert my header text? For example, can I add `(format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")` after `Date:` in my `header` file and evaluate it somehow when it is inserted?

Comment: You need something along the following lines: ```(defun header()
  "Insert header into file"
  (interactive)
  (progn (insert-file "~/.emacs.d/header")
         (re-search-backward "Date: ")
         (insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d"))))```

Comment: Whoa – that's magical! Care to turn it into an answer so I can mark this answered? (I found that I had to change `re-search-backward` to `re-search-forward` since the text is inserted after the cursor, presumably?)

Comment: There are lots of generic mechanisms for inserting templates in emacs. See e.g. [skeleton](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/autotype.html#Skeleton-Language) in the Autotyping manual. See also [Category Templates](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryTemplates) in the Emacs Wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of GNU Emacs only your imagination is the limit :)

I think you're looking for something along the following lines, though some adjustments might be needed.

```
(defun header()
  "Insert header into file"
  (interactive)
  (insert-file "~/.emacs.d/header")
  (re-search-backward "Date:")
  (insert (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d")))
```